# Conditionally Join Dataframes by Row in R

Tags: r, join

I would like to conditionally merge two tables with the following formats:

```
id1 <- c('S001', 'S002', 'S003', 'S004', 'S004')
id2 <- c('S001', 'S001', 'S002', 'S002', 'S001')
ids <- data.frame(id1, id2)
```

and

```
bad_id_key <- c('S002', 'S004') 
bad_id_val <- c('a', 'b')
bad_ids <- data.frame(bad_id_key, bad_id_val)
```

The conditional rules are:

1. If both IDs are in the "bad" list, drop that row
2. If neither ID is in the "bad" list, drop that row
3. If only one of the IDs is bad, add the bad value to the row.

The resulting table would look like:

```
  id1  id2 bad_id_val
2 S002 S001          a
3 S003 S002          a
5 S004 S001          b
```

I was able to accomplish this with the following code snippet:

```
conditionalJoin <- function(row){
  if(row$id1 %in% bad_id_key & row$id2 %in% bad_id_key){
    # do nothing
  }
  else if(row$id1 %in% bad_id_key){
    merge(x=row, y=bad_ids, by.x="id1", by.y="bad_id_key", all.x=TRUE)
  }
  else if(row$id2 %in% bad_id_key){
    merge(x=row, y=bad_ids, by.x="id2", by.y="bad_id_key", all.x=TRUE)
  }
}

out <- do.call("rbind", as.list(by(ids, 1:nrow(ids), conditionalJoin)))
```

However, this approach scales extremely poorly as the size of the ids dataframe grows.  I think this is because of the rbind function.  Also, the if elses are not very elegant R code.

Does anyone know of of an R command to do this kind of row-wise conditional joining that is more efficient than rbind?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the *data.table* package, i would approach it as follows:

```
library(data.table)
ids <- setDT(ids)[xor(id1 %in% bad_ids$bad_id_key, id2 %in% bad_ids$bad_id_key)
                  ][, bad_id_val := ifelse(id1 %in% bad_ids$bad_id_key,
                                           as.character(bad_ids$bad_id_val[match(id1, bad_ids$bad_id_key)]),
                                           as.character(bad_ids$bad_id_val[match(id2, bad_ids$bad_id_key)]))]
```

which gives the desired result:

```
> ids
    id1  id2 bad_id_val
1: S002 S001          a
2: S003 S002          a
3: S004 S001          b
```

Tested on the larger dataset of @jeremycg this gives the following outcome with regard to speed:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq       mean     median          uq         max neval cld
 jeremy   9.196898   9.386950   9.854132   9.603002    9.749256   16.764747   100  b 
     OP 974.933816 985.813821 996.770067 992.145890 1000.411484 1143.402837   100   c
   jaap   3.572531   3.612401   3.779686   3.679115    3.790707    9.803782   100 a
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the fastest I can get it using `dplyr`. It's considerably faster, as there are only two `match` calls, everything else is quick. See the benchmark below.

```
library(dplyr)
ids %>% mutate(x = match(id1, bad_ids$bad_id_key), #get the first match of id1 
               y = match(id2, bad_ids$bad_id_key)) %>% #and id2
        filter(xor(is.na(x), is.na(y))) %>% #filter to make sure we have 1 match
        mutate(val = ifelse(is.na(x), #if x didn't match
                         as.character(bad_ids$bad_id_val[y]), #get the y
                         as.character(bad_ids$bad_id_val[x]))) # otherwise get the x
```

Here's a benchmark on larger data:

```
#5000 lines of ids
set.seed(12345)
ids <- data.frame(id1 = sample(1:50, 5000, replace = TRUE), id2 = sample(1:50, 5000, replace = TRUE))
bad_ids <- data.frame(bad_id_key = 1:20, bad_id_val = letters[1:20])

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
me = {
   ids %>% mutate(x = match(id1, bad_ids$bad_id_key),
                  y = match(id2, bad_ids$bad_id_key)) %>%
           filter(xor(is.na(x), is.na(y))) %>%
           mutate(val = ifelse(is.na(x), 
                           as.character(bad_ids$bad_id_val[y]), 
                           as.character(bad_ids$bad_id_val[x])))},
OP = {out <- do.call("rbind", as.list(by(ids, 1:nrow(ids), conditionalJoin)))}
)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max
   me   11.92924   12.41934   15.36524   13.07722   15.71085   63.14211
   OP 1831.34599 1910.90149 2369.70980 2112.57251 2340.88428 5549.01191
 neval
   100
   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ifelse` functions, it is often better to just work within the `data.frame` or `data.table` its self to identify records you want to keep. For your example you could do this with the following code:

```
ids[xor(ids$id1 %in% bad_id_key, ids$id2 %in% bad_id_key),]
```

After running this code you just need to merge `ids` and `bad_ids` to append the bad id value.

Comment: why not use `xor` and do it in one step?